# Can a German citizen use tax-free shopping in Germany if he has a 6-month work visa outside the EU?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, duty-free, german-citizens

I am a German citizen with a German passport and I currently hold a J1 US Visa for 6 months. I am planning to buy a purse and import it into the US. Can I use Global Blue for this since my visa is more than 3 months valid? [This page](http://www.globalblue.com/destinations/germany/tax-free-shopping-in-germany/) for Germany sounds like I can participate in Global Blue.

> Shoppers eligible for Tax Free Shopping
>
> ● If you have a permanent residence in a non-EU country.
>
> ● If you have a valid long term Visa (more than 3 months) in a non-EU country.
>
> ● If you are older than 18 years.

Comment: Do you satisfy the first requirement -- permanent residence outside the EU? Where is that?

Comment: Global Blue might be a bit self-serving in their description, it's not only a matter of staying longer than three months abroad, you must have your ordinary residence outside of the EU as [described on official sources](http://www.zoll.de/DE/Privatpersonen/Reisen/Reisen-nach-Deutschland-aus-einem-nicht-eu-Staat/Zoll-und-Steuern/Tax-free-einkaufen/tax-free-einkaufen.html) and you will need to convince a customs agent of that (as you need a stamp from the German customs).

Comment: Incidentally, in the Schengen area, a visa valid for longer than 3 months is usually a long-term visa and people who have such a visa from an EU country are not eligible for tax-free shopping in the EU, which might be the source of the confusion. But US visas work differently, visitors visas can be valid for up to 10 years and *stays* on a visitor visa can also last 6 months. And I doubt the German customs would accept a B-visa as a proof of foreign residence.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I thought there must be only one requirement fulfilled because if **all** the requirements need to be fulfilled it is almost impossible for US Americans to use Global Blue on vacation since they don't need a visa.

Comment: I updated the question with my Visa information. It is a J1 Visa and I am going to stay in the US for that amount of time.

Comment: Freddy, I also found Global Blue's description confusing in this respect and was going to answer that to @HenningMakholm. But it does not matter, the actual eligibility criteria, per the official site, is ordinary residence or *Wohnort* in German (neither having a visa nor *permanent* residence are actually required).

Comment: Note that if you return to Germany after the six months, you might have to pay VAT again and possibly duty too. There are exemptions for people moving to Germany from another country, but you need to have owned the goods in question for a certain amount of time (for example for cars, it's one year IIRC).

Comment: @Freddy: Under an "or"-interpretation, the program would be available to everyone over 18 irrespectively of their residence, _as well as_ to minors with non-EU residence or visas. That sounds highly unlikely.

Comment: @Relaxed Ok, thank you for clarification. I plan to leave the purse handbag as a present in the US and will **not** take it back to Germany after 6 months. So it depends what the Zoll/Customs considers what my residence is, right? It is interesting to know, how a J1 Visa is considered.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I know. I find this very misleading. I think it is (1or2)AND3. Since why would a out of EU passport holder hold also a out of EU visa?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Neither interpretation fully makes sense, we already established the description is BS. And the three-month threshold is also completely beside the point when considering non-Schengen visas. I really think it's a confusion or lazy translation as you are also required *not* to stay longer than 3 months in the EU to benefit from this exemption. The question remains when considering the actual criterion (ordinary residence outside the EU), does a six-month stay under a US J1 visa count?

Comment: The official information is also available [in English](http://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Leaving-Germany/Tax-free-shopping/tax-free-shopping_node.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you de-registered (Abmeldung) yourself? If yes, then you can do tax-free shopping, since that is what Germany considers as not living in Germany anymore. I'm a German citizen living in Switzerland since 6 months, and a few months ago I got tax reimbursements for my shopping.